# Remove strings based on their dictionary value in Python

Tags: python, pandas

I want to remove strings based on their dictionary's value. The condition is that I want to remove the string if their value is the smallest among the strings in the cell and keep the string column no more than two strings. How could I achieve this?

```
fruit_dict = {
  "Apple": 10,
  "Watermelon": 20,
  "Cherry": 30,
  "Orange": 40,
  "Lemon": 50
}

df = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        "ID": [1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
        "name": [
            "Apple, Watermelon, Cherry, Lemon",
            "Cherry, Watermelon, Orange",
            "Apple, Cherry, Watermelon",
            "Cherry",
            "Cherry, Orange",
        ],
    }
)
```

Expected output:

```
   ID                        name
0   1               Cherry, Lemon
1   2              Cherry, Orange
2   3          Cherry, Watermelon
3   4                      Cherry
4   5              Cherry, Orange
```

Comment: and you dont try or attempt nothing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems solution should be simplify for get top2 values per groups like:

```
df = (df.assign(name= df['name'].str.split(', '))
        .explode('name')
        .assign(new = lambda x: x['name'].map(fruit_dict))
        .sort_values(['ID', 'new'], ascending=[True, False])
        .groupby('ID')['name']
        .agg(lambda x: ','.join(x.head(2)))
        .reset_index()
       )
print (df)
   ID               name
0   1       Lemon,Cherry
1   2      Orange,Cherry
2   3  Cherry,Watermelon
3   4             Cherry
4   5      Orange,Cherry
```

Or use `sorted` with `key` and `reverse=True`:

```
f = lambda x: ','.join(sorted(x.split(', '), 
                              key=lambda x: fruit_dict.get(x, float('-inf')), 
                              reverse = True)[:2])
df['name'] = df['name'].apply(f)


print (df)
   ID               name
0   1       Lemon,Cherry
1   2      Orange,Cherry
2   3  Cherry,Watermelon
3   4             Cherry
4   5      Orange,Cherry
```